# Building a client/server application with system.net.sockets throught client firewall and router

Tags: .net, networking, client-server, websocket

I'm making a client/server application, the application has a server application that will be located on a remote host, and a client application that could be located on different client with different IP address.
The server application will have his ip address on port 80, and it will listen the different client request.
This client/server application will support also a real time chat, so......., if the different client are behind firewall and router, could the server send real time messages to the clients application throught these firewall and router, and then waiting for them response too.

Answer (score 0):

If the ports are open...yes.

Comment: The client application has his dynamic ip address and port every time is going to connect to the web.

Comment: The client application has his dynamic ip address and port every time is going to connect to the web.
My application is always on web, and has is fixes Ip and port (80) open.1
When the client application call the server application, it call it throught his assigned ip and port by system, and then the server response to it to its ip and port.
But at this point could the server do another sent operation to the client without receving another call?

Answer (score 0):

One common way around this is to park a request on the server, and then respond to that. Most firewalls aren't going to allow you to make a request to the client. So, you make an asynchronous request to the server, and the server doesn't return until there is something meaningful to send to the client. Then, after the response is sent, have the client park another request for the next piece(s) of server data.

Comment: Very interesting Matt.
But how can i do an asynchronous request to the server, for example.
1) The Client connect to the Server throught his dynamic ip and port (123.123.123.123:12345) to server's IP and port (456.456.456.456:80)
2) The Server (456.456.456.456:80) response to the Client (123.123.123.123:12345)
3) The Client (123.123.123.123:12345) make another request without having nothing to ask to server (456.456.456.456:80), and then wait for response?
Is this do you mean?

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, then yes. The client must make a request to the server and wait for response. The server only responds when something the client cares about happens, otherwise the server just holds the connection open. Once the client gets the response, it sends another request, and you continue the communication like that.

Comment: thank Matt.
i'm looking for some examples for Asynchronous Server Socket programming , i've found this one for server side http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx and a the end of the same page there is an example for client side my client/server application will be multi clients. Since i'm new to socket programming, could you help me, am i on the right way?

thank in advance again.